# Cache Control via PHP Headers - Chrome Works / Firefox Doesn't

Tags: php, apache, caching, http-headers

I have a very simple header cache control set up on a few of my php based files (images, css, json).

To the point, chrome caches and firefox doesn't.

Here's the header code:

```
header('Cache-Control: max-age=300, must-revalidate');
header("Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + 300) . " GMT");
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are your images/css/json being served via a PHP script (as in readfile, file_get_contents, fopen, etc..) or are you generating HTML that links to images/css/json using PHP?

Comment: Yes via fopen and echoing; where through the php file headers are being sent / cached.

Comment: It would be more efficient to configure apache to do that for you. Accessing a static file through PHP is going to add a bit of overhead to the request.

Comment: Check out this site and see if this is helpful at all: [Speed up your site with Caching and cache-control](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/speed-up-your-site-with-caching-and-cache-control.html). It explains how to use different Apache modules to do what you're trying to do (and as suggested by @datasage.)

Comment: @datasage he probably needs a level and granularity of **access control** apache cannot give

Comment: Guessing: are you returning a `Content-Length`?

Answer (score 0):

Check the complete HTTP header that is actually sent to the browser with something like [Live HTTP Headers](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/)

Are you using PHP's session functions?

PHP can set certain cache HTTP headers when you use sessions. session_start() sets cache headers
which can configured with [session_cache_limiter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php). The default value for the cache limiter can be overwritten in the [php.ini](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cache-limiter). All this can get confusing when trying to set your own cache headers, so make sure you check the actual sent headers.